# determine vector equation of the tangent line to a graph at an indicated point

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Can you guys help me find a vector equation of the tangent line to a graph at point (6,2,0)? Given that the vector equation of the graph is

$$G(x(t),y(t),z(t))=3 \cdot \csc \left({\pi \over 12} \cdot t\right), log_3(5t-1), \pi-3 \cdot \sec^{-1} t$$

now I know that to find it I need the derivative of the vector which is 
$$G^{'}(x(t),y(t),z(t))={-\pi \over 4} \cdot \csc \left({\pi \over 12} t \right) \cdot \cot \left( {\pi \over 12} t \right), {5 \over {(5t-1) \cdot \ln(3)}}, {{-3} \over {t\cdot (\sqrt{t^2-1})}}$$

and evaluating it at the point $(6,2,0)$ would give me a vector $0, 5/9ln3,$ and an undefined one?

how do i get pass this? any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to learn how to typeset math. Search mathematics meta for a "mathjax tutorial".

Comment: i tried but i'm just here to ask this one question. pls can you help me? i'm desperate

Comment: I formatted your question.

Comment: thank you so much you're amazing